# Is GMAT still available? Where? How? (NASA's General Mission Analysis Tool)

Tags: nasa, mission-design, software, visualization

In [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4449/visualization-of-non-keplerian-orbits-for-solar-sails#comment9182_4449) below the question [Visualization of non-Keplerian orbits for solar sails](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4449/12102), NASA's open source General Mission Analysis Tool is suggested. Sounds great!

My google search found this [blog from 2012](http://gmat.sourceforge.net/blog/) and this big PDF [Users Guide](http://gmat.sourceforge.net/doc/R2012a/help-letter.pdf) also dated 2012, both on SourceForge. But the links I was aiming for didn't help much.

The link https://gmat.gsfc.nasa.gov/ only gives me a "your connection is not private" error (shown below) even when I delete the `s` and change it back to `http://` , and  http://opensource.gsfc.nasa.gov/projects/GMAT/index.php seems to be a dead end.

Where can I find this software? Is it something I have to compile on my computer, or is it hosted somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go beyond the expired certificate, you get a page telling you it is now supported on an [off-NASA site](http://gmatcentral.org/):

[image]

Comment: Bingo! Thank you, now I can think about "...where to go and how much to bring."